# How do I send an Authorization header via ZAPapi?

Tags: python-3.x, api, zap

I'm using a python ZAPAPI call to scan APIs. I got the Active and spider scans to run, but I'm having trouble understanding how I could send the Authorization Token as a header request.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use the replacer: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/replacer/

You can control is via the API.

Comment: Hey Simon, I'm using python to make an API call and I'm trying to send the header information via the script. The link above is for the GUI?

Comment: No, the replacer works in daemon mode as well. An example is given on https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-you-find-out-what-key-to-use-to-set-a-config-value-on-the-command-line/